# I want to show a specific row from sql table in asp.net mvc 3.1 (without ORM)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a table called products which has  9 rows of products with their own unqiue productId. I want to show the product with productId = 3. How can I do this or do you know a tutorial which van explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC - model view controller, acually MVC do not need any DB. Lets suppose you have object model, model View and controller witch perform any actions you need. So to persist object model into DB not need to use ORM. You can call DB Stored procedures, Direct table, SQL Plan Text to persist data.

sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/executing-a-command) for execute Stored procedure

```
static void GetSalesByCategory(string connectionString,
    string categoryName)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Create the command and set its properties.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SalesByCategory";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Add the input parameter and set its properties.
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@CategoryName";
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.Value = categoryName;

        // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection.
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        // Open the connection and execute the reader.
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:C}", reader[0], reader[1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

CommandType Enum

```
StoredProcedure     
TableDirect
Text
```